# ios6 ios7 xcode4.6 xcode5 dilemma

Tags: ios6, appstore-approval, xcode5

I was building an app in xcode 4.6 (ios6.1) and everything was fine.

I ran the same code through xcode 5 (ios 7) on an ios7 device and simulator, and I ran into the full screen (status bar included) issue, horizontal scrollview issues, modal viewcontroller issues, et al.

I’m using a navigation controller with the bar turned off. Instead I’m using a custom view to pass for a bar. So the extendedEdge thing isn’t working as well.

I understand that eventually, I’ll have to update my design and implementation accordingly.

Now here’s the dilemma – I ran the app (backed up original code) from xcode 4.6 (ios6) on an ios 7 device, and it’s working absolutely fine. It’s leaving it’s gap for the status bar, and there are no issues at all.

What I can’t understand now is how to proceed?

Will the app be accepted if I continue working on xcode 4.6 with ios6 (since it’s almost finished)?

I’m not able to move to xcode 5, since it has only the latest ios7 as the Base SDK.
I can’t find a legitimate way to add ios 6 sdk to xcode 5 (except copying the 6.1 SDK to the xcode5 package).

And, if I hadn’t downloaded xcode 5 DP (which installs it separately), the mac app store would have updated my xcode 4.6 to xcode 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple still accept applications submit through Xcode 4.6
But consider that you would loose some new functionality like having different icons to each OS version etc.
Moreover, your app won't use the 64-bit processor (it is still compatible but if your app is a game or something like that it is recommended to use it).

I assume that in few months you won't be able to submit apps using the old Xcode.

UPDATE:
For you to be able to use status bar as before (like hidden), in your apps plist file add a row call it "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO

Comment: Thanks @idan . There's nothing new that I can use in my app (simple news app). Is there any official announcement which says that Xcode 4.6 submissions are still on?

Comment: I just submitted few apps with Xcode 4.6, There is nothing formal I know of but it is usually around 3 months. I've updated the answer a bit maybe that would help with status bar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update people who might be looking for an answer to this -

Apple will only accept apps and updates made with **Xcode 5** on **iOS 7**, effective **1st Feb 2014**.